# Positioning Scroll Bar

Tags: css, reactjs

Generally when a scroll bar is applied, it starts from starting of the page. I need it to start right from where the the DOM element specified starts.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
function Home(){
  return (<h1 style={{position:'fixed'}}>Home</h1>);
}
function Contact(){
  return (<h1 style={{position:'absolute',top:'40px',height:'200vh',background:'skyblue',width:'100vw'}}>
    Contact</h1>);
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home />
      <Contact />
    
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Result]

I've applied `height:200vh` to Contact Component. The scrolling bar has to start only from Contact DOM element. Home component's position should be fixed always. This is just a demo as I'll be using the suggestion to work on my Single Page Application. Any help would be great.
**Thanks in Advance.!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

body should have `overflow-y: hidden` while Contact should have `overflow-y: scroll` or `overflow-y: auto`

```
// App.js

import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
function Home() {
  return (
    <h1
      style={{
        margin: 0
      }}
    >
      Home
    </h1>
  );
}
function Contact() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        background: "skyblue none repeat scroll 0% 0%",
        position: "absolute",
        top: "40px",
        bottom: 0,
        width: "100%",
        overflowY: "scroll"
      }}
    >
      <h1
        style={{
          height: "200vh",
          margin: 0
        }}
      >
        Contact
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home />
      <Contact />
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

```
// styles.css

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

[image: Edit sharp-robinson-rie2y]